# Check Common Dropdown Items (JavaScript, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help with the following code.

So I have a page like the following one in the example.

So far, I tried the following method. (Please check my code and live example)

With my current method to select the checkboxes, I have to write code for each and every option like this.

```
$("#check_us, #check_us-1, #check_us-2").prop("checked", !0)
```

Is there any simpler way to do this? for an example can we just select every one which contains `us_, as_, eu` part without assigning unique values to every option. Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$("button.select-all").on("click", selectAll);

function selectAll() {
    $(".schoolareas").toArray().forEach(function (a, c, b) {
        $("#check_" + a.id).prop("checked", !0)
    })
}
$("button.unselect-all").on("click", unselectAll);

function unselectAll() {
    $(".schoolareas").toArray().forEach(function (a, c, b) {
        $("#check_" + a.id).prop("checked", !1)
    })
}

$("button.select-us").on("click", selectAmerica);

function selectAmerica() {
    unselectAll();
    $(".schoolareas").toArray();
    $("#check_us, #check_us-1, #check_us-2").prop("checked", !0)
}
$("button.select-eu").on("click", selectEurope);

function selectEurope() {
    unselectAll();
    $(".schoolareas").toArray();
    $("#check_eu, #check_eu-1").prop("checked", !0)
}


$("button.select-as").on("click", selectAsia);
function selectAsia() {
    unselectAll();
    $(".schoolareas").toArray();
    $("#check_as, #check_as-1").prop("checked", !0)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid py-4">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-8 offset-2">
      <div class="btn-groups">
        <button class="btn btn-primary select-all">Select All</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary unselect-all">Unselect All</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="latencybutton">Count</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Country/Area</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
          <button class="dropdown-item select-us" type="button">America</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item select-eu" type="button">Europe</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item select-as" type="button">Asia</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container col-8 offset-2">
  <div class="table-responsive  shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-light rounded text-xs-center">
    <table id="grid" class="table table-hover">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th data-type="string">?</th>
          <th data-type="string">Locations:</th>
          <th data-type="number">Scores:</th>
          <th data-type="number">Average:</th>
          <th class="thmw" data-type="string">Score Status:</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check_eu" checked />
            <label for="check_eu"></label>
          </td>
          <td>London (EU)</td>
          <td class="schoolareas" id="eu"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="status"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check_eu-1" checked />
            <label for="check_eu-1"></label>
          </td>
          <td>Manchester (EU)</td>
          <td class="schoolareas" id="eu-1"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="status"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check_us" checked />
            <label for="check_us"></label>
          </td>
          <td>New York (US)</td>
          <td class="schoolareas" id="us"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="status"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check_us-1" checked />
            <label for="check_us-1"></label>
          </td>
          <td>California (US)</td>
          <td class="schoolareas" id="us-1"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="status"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check_us-2" checked />
            <label for="check_us-2"></label>
          </td>
          <td>Florida (US)</td>
          <td class="schoolareas" id="us-2"></td>
          <td class="status"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check_as" checked />
            <label for="check_as"></label>
          </td>
          <td>Singapore (AS)</td>
          <td class="schoolareas" id="as"></td>
          <td class="status"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check_as-1" checked />
            <label for="check_as-1"></label>
          </td>
          <td>China (AS)</td>
          <td class="schoolareas" id="as-1"></td>
          <td class="status"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As a side note, I strongly suggest that you avoid using jQuery while you are learning JavaScript. Young JavaScript programmers are often confused about where JavaScript ends and jQuery begins. They also don't realize all of the powerful features that are now built into JavaScript, such as document.querySelector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can! Instead of accessing elements by their IDs (which have to be unique), give them all a common class and grab them by that instead.

So elements that look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check_us-1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" id="check_us-2" checked />
```

Get an additional class prop, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check_us-1" class="us" checked />
<input type="checkbox" id="check_us-2" class="us" checked />
```

Then you can update their props in batch like this:

```
$(".us").prop("checked", !0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Without modifying your current HTML you can select all elements wich class contains a string with:

```
$('checkbox[class^="us"]')
```

and changed their checkbox value like this:

```
$('checkbox[class^="us"]').prop("checked", !0)
```

then change us for whatever word you want.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways you can do this using either JavaScript or jQuery.

You could use the [attribute contains](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector to find all elements with an id that matches a pattern:

```
$('[id*="us_"]').prop('checked', true);
```

This form of selector also works with JavaScript's native [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method.

However, this runs the risk of unintentionally selecting irrelevant elements that happen to match the selector. The selector above would also match an element with an id of "status_code", for example.

A better approach is the one that @jonny suggests in his answer. While the id attribute of every element in a document has to be unique, other attributes like "class" do not. This allows you to assign a css class name to a group of related elements and select them by that class name using the [class](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) selector. (Again, this selector also works with the [`document.querySelector`  method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)).

Personally, I dislike using css class names to select related groups of elements because css classes are for styling, not for functionality. So another approach you can use if you want to keep style an function separate is to include [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check_us-1" checked data-group="us" />
<input type="checkbox" id="check_us-2" checked data-group="us" />
```

You can then use the attribute selector to select both inputs:

```
$('[data-group="us"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Hi, if you wouldn't mind can you please explain me how the unselect and select all options will work with your   $('[data-group="us"]').prop('checked', true); method? :)

Comment: I would be happy to, but I'm not sure what you mean by the "unselect and select all options."

Comment: Thanks :D. Please check on my live example. The "select all" and "unselect all" button. When I click on the select all button, it selects all, and when I click on unselect it unselect all of the checkboxes. 

But how do we do that with your $('[data-group="us"]').prop('checked', true); method?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your love example? I don't see one anywhere in your question.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to copy it. Once you click on Run Code Snippet, it will launch the live version.

Comment: I see. Looks like it doesn't work because I'm using the mobile app. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200425/discussion-between-daniel-arant-and-gihan).